# Set HTTP Options Response w/ Claudia-Api-Builder for AWS ApiGateway

Tags: node.js, http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, claudiajs

I am trying to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header for `options` and it appears currently that *claudia-api-builder* does not have the ability to set the  http options response, like a `GET` request would. See GET example below.

**GET Example**

```
api.get('/hard-coded-headers', function () {
   return 'OK';
}, {success: {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS'}}});
```

Furthermore ...

If this header value is set via `aws-api-gateway -> resources -> OPTIONS > Integration Response` and then if you were to perform a `claudia update` it would be overwritten back to its default state as seen below.

[image: AWS-ApiGateway Custom mapping response setting]

The `claudia-api-builder` docs show that it supports API Gateway custom error responses but nothing for success.

I would like to be able to set options custom header responses like the way a GET request is handled. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `new ApiResponse()` function?

```
api.get('/programmatic-headers', function () {
  return new api.ApiResponse('OK', {'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS'}, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than the site currently in use.

you can guarantee permission to a domain (or several), http verb or contentType

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'example.com');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```